# Unable to run LOOPS within Javascript Ruby on Rails View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Executive Summary

1. Question 1: What is the value of providing local variables to a render, when they can access the instance objects in the controller?
2. Issue:  I can NOT run a ruby loop within my _error.js.erb file. The goal of this loop is to provide DIRECT output to a $("#error_explanation") id regarding all of the
3. I was able to run the various other jquery commands as illustrated below.
4. I am able to run straight JQUERY commands leveraging ruby.

Dear Friends,

In my create controller, within it is the following:

```
format.js { render "_error.js.erb", locals: {post: @post, errors: @post.errors.messages}  }
```

In my VIEW _error.js.erb, i have 3 JQUERY queries, two of them work, but the third does not work.

```
This Works. $("#error_explanation").append('<%= j pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this secret from being saved: <p>');

This Works. $("#error_explanation").append('<%= post.errors.full_messages_for(:title) %>');


This Does NOT Work. $("#error_explanation").append('
    <% post.errors.messages.each do |error| %>
     <%= j error %>
    <% end %>
```

I can only assume that it is because of my loop? Can I not perform loops in my javascript (js.erb) code?

Resulted in this Error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for ["Title can't be blank", "Subject can't be blank"]:Array):
     5: <% end %>
     6: 
     7: <% if post.errors.full_messages[1] %>
     8: $("#error_explanation").append('<%= j(post.errors.full_messages.each {|n| n}) %>');
     9: <% end %>
    10: $("#error_explanation").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: I am thinking because of multi line. Can you try running the loop before and putting all error in a variable 'result' and then append(result)

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for [:title, ["can't be blank"]]:Array):%- str = "" %>
<% post.errors.messages.each do |error| %>
  <% str+= error %>
<% end %>');    
$("#error_explanation").append("<%= j str %>");

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
$("#error_explanation").append("<%= j(post.errors.full_messages.each{|msg| msg }) %>")
```

or

```
 <%- str = "" %>
 <% if post.errors %>
    <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
      <% str+= error %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>  
 $("#error_explanation").append("<%= j str %>");
```

Comment: <%- str %> Is this the method to CREATE a local variable within the view?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Array into String)?

Comment: i have edited ans., you can check it if u r still stuck in this.

Comment: Why is there an extra ');

Comment: sry it was typing mistake